# Apache Tapestry: Absolute path to assets in META-INF/assets

Tags: java, tapestry

The solution here helps me get absolute path to assets in class-path (context)
[Tapestry 5 - Dynamically generate URL of file in web app context folder in Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307134/tapestry-5-dynamically-generate-url-of-file-in-web-app-context-folder-in-java)

Is there a way to do the same for assets stored in META-INF/assets (Tapestry 5.4 way of storing assets)?

Specifically, I'd like to inject the path of the a .html (static) file I've created in META-INF/assets folder..

at the moment I have:

```
public String getMyHtml() {
    String clientURL = assetSource.getContextAsset("html/myhtml.html", locale).toClientURL();

    return clientURL;
}
```

and the tml file has:

```
"{ url: '${getDeltaHtml()}' }"
```

This works if `"myhtml.html"` file is located in class path folder (WEB-INF). It does not work if its in META-INF/assets folder, which is where I'd like to put it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get hold of the assets stored under assets by this.

First you have to inject the following.

```
@Inject
private AssetSource assetSource;

@Inject
private ThreadLocale threadLocale;
```

After that you can use the following to get the Assets.

```
Asset asset = assetSource.getAsset(null, "classpath:META-INF/assets/myhtml.html", threadLocale.getLocale());
```